# Remove header of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to remove the following header part from a blob uploaded to the controller. I tried using the `GET` method but then the data cannot be loaded. This header prevent the file from being properly played.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRxmjN7irF2fjoibL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="that_random_filename.wav"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: audio/wav
```

**Controller**

```
        public JsonResult SubmitSound()
        {
            var length = Request.ContentLength;
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, length);

            // Create the new, empty data file.
            string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Content/Sound/" + Environment.TickCount + ".wav";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            w.Write(bytes);
            w.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return new JsonResult() { Data = "Saved successfully" };
        }
```

**Edit**

I use `recordjs` by Matt Diamond ([demo](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html), works only on Chrome), a library that record speech, save it as a blob in a javascript variable. This is kind of hard logic that I cannot change that blob to file, basically because it is just a variable in memory.

**View**

```
    function doneEncoding(blob) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("that_random_filename.wav", blob);
        console.log(fd);
        xhr.open("POST", "/Home/SubmitSound", true);
        xhr.send(fd);
        Recorder.forceDownload(blob, "myRecording" + ((recIndex < 10) ? "0" : "") + recIndex + ".wav");
        recIndex++;
    }
```

I can manually remove the first nth byte of the array, but it is not elegant enough for me. Could you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting a file from your form, even if its via AJAX, then the form and content disposition really should be kept. You should not delete it. The easy way to receive a file in Controller action then use a

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitSound(HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

and then do something like this in you controller method.

```
MemoryStream fs= new MemoryStream();
file.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
```

Comment: The point is I am not uploading a file, but rather a **blob** created by javascript.

Comment: Sorry, don't have your JavaScript for reference and the form boundary / content disposition info says its a file - have you already tried to accept it like a file as I suggested?

Comment: OK, you put the data into 'that_random_filename.wav' if you put it into a form field called 'file' instead, then it matches the method signature I gave and should have everything it needs to work.